# C# Parallel - Duplicate iteration

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing strange issue where files in iteration are being called twice.

```
Parallel.ForEach(context.files.Where(x => x.in_queue == true && x.Uploaded == false), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (fl, state) =>
                {
                    //File upload code
                        fl.in_queue = false;
                        fl.Uploaded = true;
                        log.Debug(string.Format("{0} uploaded", fl.FileName));
                });
```

I am seeing same files more than once in the log, but the context doesn't contain any duplicate entries.

Comment: Where does this code occur ? What's calling it ? Is it possible that this code is executed more than once ? What is `context` and so on. It's difficult to say anything without knowing more

Comment: context is ienumerable of custom object. Its inside a synchronous function.

Comment: Before setting up a test case for this, can you refactor your code a litte bit like this and confirm that the issue is still there? `var files = context.files.Where(x => x.in_queue == true && x.Uploaded == false).ToList(); Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (fl, state) => ...`

Comment: Yeah, had tried that. I made the list, issue is still there.

Comment: It seems likely that this code is being called more than once simultaneously.  The flags that exclude a file from processing are not being set until *after* they are uploaded.  Since the upload takes time, if there were another instance of this code running, you would get duplicate uploads.  One way to protect against this might be to add a `.uploading` flag that you both check set *before* the upload is started (and if the upload fails then reset it).  Alternatively, put a lock on this code so it cannot be entered simultaneously.

Comment: RBarryYougn, you were right. Method was being called twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit test that shows issue is not reproducable using plain code.

Like @RBarryYoung points to, a concurrency issue is most likely the problem.

```
public class CustomFile
{
    public bool in_queue { get; set; }
    public bool Uploaded { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void ParallelTest()
{
    var files = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
        .Select(it =>
            new CustomFile {in_queue = true, Uploaded = false, FileName = $"{it}_my_file.txt"}
        );

    var usedFileNames = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    Parallel.ForEach(files
            .Where(x => x.in_queue == true && x.Uploaded == false),
        new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, (fl) =>
        {
            fl.in_queue = false;
            fl.Uploaded = true;
            usedFileNames.Add(fl.FileName);
        });

    Assert.IsFalse(usedFileNames.GroupBy(x => x).Any(x => x.Count() > 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was calling the parent method twice which was pushing the uploader twice. Thanks for the efforts and showing excellent method to troubleshoot this issue.